# Count the number of occurances of multiple letters in a variable within a dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Just say I want to cont the number of "a"'s and "p"'s in the word "apple", I can do:

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count("apple", c("b", "k")))
```

but when I try to apply this logic in order to count the number of "a"'s and "p"'s across multiple different words in a variable in a dataframe, it doesn't work, e.g.:

```
dat <- tibble(id = 1:4, word = c(c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")))
dat <- dat %>% mutate(num_ap = sum(str_count(word, c("a", "p"))))
```

it doesn't work. I the variable "num_ap" should read `c(3, 3, 2, 4)` but instead it reads `c(5, 5, 5, 5)`

Does anyone know why this isn't working for me?

Thanks!

Comment: add rowwise() before mutate should do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this it helps to backtrack the issue.

`str_count(dat$word, c("a", "p"))` by itself will return `[1] 1 0 1 3`. Each number represents the number of times the letter 'p' appears in each word in your data frame. If you take the sum of that vector with `sum(str_count(dat$word, c("a", "p")))`, you get `[1] 5`. Since you are not going row by row, each row will be assigned a value of 5, which is consistent with your results.

To fix this, note that the function `rowwise()` (part of the `dplyr` library) allows you to do work with each row individually. Hence, modifying your code to incorporate the `rowwise()` function will solve your problem:

```
dat <- dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(num_ap = sum(str_count(word, c("a", "p"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`sapply` the transformation to each element of `dat$word`

```r
library(stringr)
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:4, word = c(c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")))
dat$num_ap <- sapply(dat$word, function(x) sum(str_count(x, c("a", "p"))))

dat
#>   id      word num_ap
#> 1  1     apple      3
#> 2  2    banana      3
#> 3  3      pear      2
#> 4  4 pineapple      4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions (both without `sum`):

with `rowwise()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(num_ap = str_count(word, "a|p"))
  id      word num_ap
1  1     apple      3
2  2    banana      3
3  3      pear      2
4  4 pineapple      4
```

with `lengths` and `str_extract_all`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>%
  mutate(num_ap = lengths(str_extract_all(word, "a|p")))
  id      word num_ap
1  1     apple      3
2  2    banana      3
3  3      pear      2
4  4 pineapple      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
dat$num_ap <-  nchar(gsub("[^ap]", "", dat$word))
```

-output

```
> dat
  id      word num_ap
1  1     apple      3
2  2    banana      3
3  3      pear      2
4  4 pineapple      4
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:4, word = c("apple", "banana", "pear", 
"pineapple")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```